# Sudden error in js to get first element by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this for ages:

```
function findFirstChildByClass(element, className) {
    var foundElement = null, found;
    function recurse(element, className, found) {
        for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length && !found; i++) {
            var el = element.childNodes[i];
            var classes = el.className != undefined? el.className.split(" ") : [];
            for (var j = 0, jl = classes.length; j < jl; j++) {
                if (classes[j] == className) {
                    found = true;
                    foundElement = element.childNodes[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found)
                break;
            recurse(element.childNodes[i], className, found);
        }
    }
    recurse(element, className, false);
    return foundElement;
}
```

But suddenly, this line throws an error:

```
var classes = el.className != undefined? el.className.split(" ") : [];
```

> Uncaught TypeError: el.className.split is not a function

I can't see right now what's wrong.

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(el.className)` to see what it is?

Comment: Why are you using this complicated function in the first place? 
Can't you just use `element.querySelector(".className")`

Comment: That's right, why are you rewriting native JS functions? You could also use [element.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: this is related to a know problem with complex svg classes. I recently moved icon to svg fontawesome. I fixed it using a type check on classes.

Comment: @BjørnNyborg I might indeed reconsider my approach. It's coded for a very long time. In the emergency, I did concentrate of fixing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related of the use of svg complex class name. Before refactoring everything, I quickly fixed the issue replacing the wrong line.

```
if (el.className != undefined && typeof(el.className) === 'string') {
                classes = el.className.split(" ")
            } else {
                classes = []
            }
```

The className property on svg elements is an Object type SVGAnimatedString and therefore doesn't have the split method.